# outlook time difference in meetings

Tags: time, outlook, ms-office

dears, i know my question is not about programming but i hope that someone would be able to help me , i have  office 2013 and when i am invited to to a meeting through outlook the time doesn't sync between the two different time zones .
for example if i am ahead by 2 hrs and i got invited to a meeting outlook doesn't recalculate the time .
is it a windows thing or an outlook option ?i have checked the outlook options ,calendar , time zones it was correct and so was my windows clock.
i am only facing this issue on two laptops in my class the rest is working perfectly , outlook changes the meeting time to adjust with my time zone.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed not the place to ask this question. Ask google and you'll get things like:

```
http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/appointments-and-time-zones/
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2642044
```

Make sure you and your counterpart have the time zones set correctly (regional settings). Alternatively, you may try to work with dual timezone.

Try asking in the Microsoft forums, those people are really helpful and the will know these tools.

Comment: i have checked almost every link out there and i have reached to Microsoft support , and as i said my time zone and the clock are all set correctly , anyways thank you .

Comment: I think that is worth mentioning in the question: you have already tried something, which is the least people will expect from you before considering devoting time to the question.

Comment: One last thought (based on a problem from somebody else): Make sure those computers with the problem have both Outlook and Windows time zones set to the one corresponding to the location where you are. That misalignment can be tricky.

Comment: Out of ideas now.
Which one is the computer changing time zones? the problem-sufferer or the meeting-scheduler?
If the answer is "none", then I don't see any light in this tunnel.